# Add profile picture filed joomla 2.5

Tags: php, joomla, joomla2.5

I'm trying to extend my joomla user profile via joomla user profile extend plugin.
I need to allow users to upload their avatar when they are registering with site. 
is there any easy way to gain this with out touching joomla core ?
I read that doing some simple hack to user form xml file will allow this feature. but I dont want to change core.

I tried joomla user profile picture plugin as well. I dont want to use joom social or that kind large plugin . I just need simple way to add user profile picture to my joomla site.

thank you very much .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this plugin for Profile Picture implementation without change any Joomla core files.

http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/clients-a-communities/user-management/19702

Check with this ... this may helps you...

Comment: Thank you for quick response. I'll check it and let you know . again thank you

Comment: I already used it. but it pop some error even I add allowed image type
"No valid image provided"  something like that.

did you used it and got results ?

Comment: I am getting only the error when we upload big image. But this plugin was working  fine...

Comment: Is there any suggested image size  & extension ? I used .jpg
I also installed user profile extend plugin as well. does it conflicts with user profile picture plugin ??

Comment: can u disable user profile extend plugin and check this plugin  now..?

Comment: I installed fresh copy of joomla 2.5.6 and test the plugin.
prompted following error
Registration failed: Registration failed: No valid image was loaded.

Comment: Yes I get it done. The issue was default enctype set to accept only text inputs. I changed it to multipart/form-data and problem solved.

Answer (score 1):

I know it's a rather big system, but you might want to consider using [Community Builder](http://www.joomlapolis.com/downloads/doc_details/451-community-builder-19-package). It's a big user management system and comes in very hand as it integrates with other 3rd party extensions such as the Kunena forum. I use this in my site and successfully added a profile picture field.

Comment: thank you very much for the information. But rather than using such complex plugin I prefer to use simple image plugin.